# Print Data From Only Specific Tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am using Access VBA to connect to SQL Server and print out table information from a specified database.  I can connect, and I can print out table information no problem.  When I add an `IF` statement, my code just goes and goes and never prints out the desired result.  For example, my `Debug.Print` statement will return

```
Test_1
Test_2
Red
Blue
```

however, if I uncomment the if statement and attempt to execute the syntax, no error is thrown and access just freezes up on me.  My desired outcome is to print the two table names that are `Like Test*`  How should my syntax be altered in order to have this data printed?

```
Public Sub GetTableNames()
Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
Dim f As ADODB.Field
Set c = New ADODB.Connection
With c
.Provider = "sqloledb.1"
With .Properties
    .Item("Data Source") = "server"
    .Item("Initial Catalog") = "database"
    .Item("PassWord") = "password"
    .Item("User ID") = "userid"
End With
.Open
Set r = .OpenSchema(adSchemaTables,Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, "TABLE"))
With r
    While Not .EOF
        'IF (.Fields("Table_Name") LIKE "Test*") THEN
            Debug.Print .Fields("TABLE_NAME"), .Fields("TABLE_TYPE")
            .MoveNext
        'END IF
    Wend
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  Your issue is not with the `IF` statement, it is with the positioning of the `.MoveNext`  Since that statement is inside the `IF` block, you are never iterating to the next table so each pass you are only looking at the first table.  With that being said, I assume that `Blue` is your first table name.

Change your code to this and you will be all set.

```
Public Sub GetTableNames()
Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
Dim f As ADODB.Field
Set c = New ADODB.Connection
With c
.Provider = "sqloledb.1"
With .Properties
.Item("Data Source") = "server"
.Item("Initial Catalog") = "database"
.Item("PassWord") = "password"
.Item("User ID") = "userid"
End With
.Open
Set r = .OpenSchema(adSchemaTables,Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, "TABLE"))
With r
While Not .EOF
    IF (.Fields("Table_Name") LIKE "Test*") THEN
        Debug.Print .Fields("TABLE_NAME"), .Fields("TABLE_TYPE")            
    END IF
    .MoveNext
Wend
End With
End With
End Sub
```